# Android Sqlite Delete related tables

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, cascade

I have the following tablescheme:  //Solution edited below!

[image: Exampe]

You can see a generalization **[disjoint, total]**.
When I delete a row in the Relation "Ziel" i would like to delete the related row in the related table.

Exampe with one entry in Koerper-Ziel:

R(Ziel) = {{1, 7, null, null, ...}}

R(Koerper-Ziel) = {{7, ...}}

delete(1) will delete both entries^

SQLite Code:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_OPTION       + " INTEGER, "   +
            COLUMN_TENDENZ      + " INTEGER );";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_EXTRA        + " TEXT );";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_EXTRA        + " TEXT, "      +
            COLUMN_MUSKEL       + " TEXT, "      +
            COLUMN_WIEDERHOLUNGEN + " INTEGER );";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NAME         + " TEXT, "      +
            COLUMN_ERSTELLDATUM + " LONG, "      +
            COLUMN_DEADLINE     + " LONG, "      +
            COLUMN_DONE         + " INTEGER, "   +
            COLUMN_VALUE        + " FLOAT, "     +
            COLUMN_FORTSCHRITT  + " FLOAT, "     +
            COLUMN_K_ID         + " INTEGER, "   +
            COLUMN_C_ID         + " INTEGER, "   +
            COLUMN_T_ID         + " INTEGER, "   +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_K_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER      + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_C_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO       + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_T_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING     + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE  " +
            ");";
```

But it does not work yet.
I think the problem is that the `DELETE ON CASCADE` works only in the reverse direction. How do I have to change my code?

EDIT:

```
  @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    }
```

Adding a Koerperziel:

```
private long addKoerperziel(KoerperZiel ziel){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        //Anlegen in der Relation TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER
        values.put(COLUMN_OPTION,       ziel.getKoerperZielOption());
        values.put(COLUMN_TENDENZ,      ziel.getTendenz());
        long kID = db.insert(TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER, null, values);
        //Anlegen in der Relation TABLE_ZIELE mit der kID als Fremdschluessel
        values.clear();
        values.put(COLUMN_K_ID, kID);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME,         ziel.name);
        values.put(COLUMN_ERSTELLDATUM, ziel.erstellDatum.getTime());
        values.put(COLUMN_DEADLINE,     ziel.deadline.getTime());
        values.put(COLUMN_DONE,         ziel.isDone());
        values.put(COLUMN_VALUE,        umrechnenKoerperZielValue1Add(ziel.getKoerperZielOption(), ziel.value));
        values.put(COLUMN_FORTSCHRITT,  ziel.progress);
        return db.insert(TABLE_ZIELE, null, values);
    }
```

EDIT 2:

```
 private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_OPTION       + " INTEGER, "   +
            COLUMN_TENDENZ      + " INTEGER, "   +
            COLUMN_Z_ID         + " INTEGER, "   +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_Z_ID + ")   REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE      + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE"  +
            ");";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_EXTRA        + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_Z_ID         + " INTEGER, "   +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_Z_ID + ")   REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE      + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE"  +
            ");";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_EXTRA        + " TEXT, "      +
            COLUMN_MUSKEL       + " TEXT, "      +
            COLUMN_WIEDERHOLUNGEN + " INTEGER, " +
            COLUMN_Z_ID         + " INTEGER, "   +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_Z_ID + ")   REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE      + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE"  +
            ");";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NAME         + " TEXT, "         +
            COLUMN_ERSTELLDATUM + " LONG, "         +
            COLUMN_DEADLINE     + " LONG, "         +
            COLUMN_DONE         + " INTEGER, "      +
            COLUMN_VALUE        + " FLOAT, "        +
            COLUMN_FORTSCHRITT  + " FLOAT );";
```

**SOLUTION**

```
 private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "    +
            COLUMN_OPTION       + " INTEGER, "                              +
            COLUMN_TENDENZ      + " INTEGER, "                              +
            COLUMN_Z_ID         + " INTEGER, "                              +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_Z_ID + ")   REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE      + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE"  +
            ");";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID           + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "    +
            COLUMN_EXTRA        + " TEXT,"                                  +
            COLUMN_Z_ID         + " INTEGER, "                              +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_Z_ID + ")   REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE      + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE"  +
            ");";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID               + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "    +
            COLUMN_EXTRA            + " TEXT, "                                 +
            COLUMN_MUSKEL           + " TEXT, "                                 +
            COLUMN_WIEDERHOLUNGEN   + " INTEGER, "                              +
            COLUMN_Z_ID             + " INTEGER, "                              +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + COLUMN_Z_ID + ")   REFERENCES " + TABLE_ZIELE      + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")  ON DELETE CASCADE"  +
            ");";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ZIELE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ZIELE + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NAME         + " TEXT, "         +
            COLUMN_ERSTELLDATUM + " LONG, "         +
            COLUMN_DEADLINE     + " LONG, "         +
            COLUMN_DONE         + " INTEGER, "      +
            COLUMN_VALUE        + " FLOAT );";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On delete cascade is only going to delete if there is an entry in the referenced table that is deleted. So to get the cascade effect either do your deletes from the KID, CID, TID tables or if you want to delete from the ZIEL table and have it cascade move your foreign key constraints the the KID, CID, TID tables;

I would also advise changing your schema so that the KID, CID, TID tables each has a ZIEL id, that would get rid of your need for null KID, CID, or TID values in the ZIEL table.

This is how I would change your schema (based on what I know about what you are trying to do)

TABLE_ZIELE

```
COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_ERSTELLDATUM, COLUMN_DEADLINE, COLUMN_DONE, COLUMN_VALUE, COLUMN_FORTSCHRITT
```

TABLE_ZIELE_KOERPER

```
COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_OPTION, COLUMN_TENDENZ, ZIEL_ID -> FOREIGN KEY(ZIEL_ID) REFERENCES ZIEL(COLUMN_ID)
```

TABLE_ZIELE_CARDIO

```
COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_EXTRA, ZIEL_ID -> FOREIGN KEY(ZIEL_ID) REFERENCES ZIEL(COLUMN_ID)
```

TABLE_ZIELE_TRAINING

```
COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_EXTRA, COLUMN_MUSKEL, COLUMN_WIEDERHOLUNGEN, ZIEL_ID -> FOREIGN KEY(ZIEL_ID) REFERENCES ZIEL(COLUMN_ID)
```

Now if you delete from the TABLE_ZIEL it will cascade up and remove the entry in the associated KOERPER, CARDIO, or TRAINING table

Comment: Ok added. In an other relation the delete on cascade works.

Comment: Are you sure that your id's are identical in both tables? What is setting the COLUMN_K, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_T id's in the parent table (ZIELE)? The auto increment in the children seems strange to me because they are at best a one to one relation, every new entry in the child will result in a different id (and will need a new parent to reference it). Of course if it is one to one that is fine, just curious of the intention

Comment: Okay, so if I understand this correctly there can only be one KOERPER-ZIEL entry for each ZIEL entry. Since you are creating a ZIEL entry every time you insert into KOERPER-ZIEL? Also, what do you do when you want to add say a CARDIO-ZIELE entry to an existing ZIEL entry. I am just trying to understand the design as I am having issues finding the bug

Comment: One Ziel-entry refers to one special Ziel. So one of the foreign keys has an id and the other two are null.

Comment: This is total-disjoint generalization. I learned that at the university.

Comment: I edited my answer, after learning more about what you were doing I was able to figure out the issue and could reproduce it on my machine

Comment: Take a look at edit2^^. But are the COLUMN IDS necassary in TABLE_ZIELE_XXX? Or can they be removed?

Comment: They could be removed, I kept them because they were in there (and I wasn't sure if you referenced them or planned on referencing them from anywhere else).

Comment: Maybe I will need they later. I'll stay with them. I'll try this solution now.

Comment: Sounds good note that you want to create the table ZIEL before the others in the code so that it knows what to reference.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!